# How to conference call with FaceTime audio?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, facetime

I'm trying to do a 3-way call on my iPhone with two friends who both are running iOS 9 (as am I).

I click the "add" button while in a call with one person and whenever I click their name or click the call button it instead hangs up my original call and calls the new person.

As per this **[source](http://www.iphonehacks.com/2014/06/ios-8-conference-calls.html)**, it should be possible as of iOS 8. Can anyone provide some insight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to have group call with *Facetime Audio* at this time. Apple used to have this feature in *iChat* but removed it because it was a poor experience.

There are other third-party apps that have this type of feature and those might fit your needs.

**EDIT**: *Adding additional info from the discussion in comments*.
The date of that [article](http://www.iphonehacks.com/2014/06/ios-8-conference-calls.html) was June 2014 and was talking about pre-release iOS 8 (which came out in Sept 2014). Maybe it was available in the beta, I don't know. Like you, the articles I read all came out around the same time and it looks like they're all using the same wording leading me to believe they're all using the same source. I could be wrong but I can't find anything on Apple's product or support pages indicating how to do this.